# How to replace exact keyword in a sentence in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextview

i got a problem where below codes not only replacing firstString with secondString but put secondString in front of a sentence. My question is how do i replace this firstString? is replacingCharacters is the right method?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
let firstString: String = "xxx"
let secondString: String = "yyy"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.text = "this \(firstString) is an example of a sentence"
    }

    func replace() {
        var finalString: String?
        let range = firstString.startIndex..<firstString.endIndex
        print(firstString[range])

        finalString = textView.text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: secondString)
        textView.text = finalString
    }

    @IBAction func replaceButton(_ sender: Any) {
    replace()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need to replace any occurrences of your firstString then you should use: `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` like so:

```
textView.text.replacingCharacters(of: firstString, with: secondString)
```

and the reason why you are getting the problem where secondString is in front of a sentence is because in your replace method:

```
func replace() {
    var finalString: String?
    let range = firstString.startIndex..<firstString.endIndex
    print(firstString[range])

    finalString = textView.text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: secondString)
    textView.text = finalString
}
```

you are trying to get the range of firstString:

```
let range = firstString.startIndex..<firstString.endIndex
```

and attempting to apply that range to your textview's string which is a totally different string from firstString therefore the range you are supplying is not what you are intending. Your `firstString` and textview text are different therefore they are going to have different ranges, it's not good to use range values of one string with another string

**EDIT:**
If you really want to replace the string by finding/using the range, then you need to first detect what's is the range you want to replace the text in, that means in your textview text which is

"this (firstString) is an example of a sentence"

you'll need to find the range `firstString` in that sentence by replacing:

```
let range = firstString.startIndex..<firstString.endIndex
```

with

```
let range = textView.text.range(of: firstString)
```

the `func range(of searchString: String) -> NSRange` will "Finds and returns the range of the first occurrence of a given string within the receiver." according the documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1410144-range

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to achieve what you are doing,

```
textview.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: firstString, with: secondString)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a **word** by another, then you should go for the `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)` method:

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in
>   the receiver are replaced by another given string.

To give you an example:

```
let originalString = "I live in Paris"

let updatedString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: "Paris", with: "New-York")

print(updatedString) // Prints "I live in New-York"
```

And in your case, you would have something like that:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: @IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    // MARK: Properties

    let firstString: String = "pink"
    let secondString: String = "blue"

    // MARK: Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.text = "The sky is \(firstString)"
        print(textView.text) // Prints "The sky is pink"
    }

    // MARK: User Interaction

    @IBAction func replaceButton(_ sender: Any) {

        let originalString = textView.text

        let updatedString = originalString.replacingOccurrences(of: firstString, with: secondString)

        print(updatedString) // Prints "The sky is blue"

        // Now you can set your text view's text to be equal to your updated string if you want :

        textView.text = updatedString

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController 
{
 @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    let firstString: String = "xxx"
    let secondString: String = "yyy"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        textView.text = "this \(firstString) is an example of a sentence"

    }
    func replace() {
       var finalString: String?
       let originalString = textView.text
       finalString = originalString?.replacingOccurrences(of: 
firstString, with: secondString)
       textView.text = finalString
    }

    @IBAction func replaceButton(_ sender: Any) {
        replace()
    }
}
```