# update/replace text in textview

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have a TextField in the first view controller where the user enter his name. In the second view controller i Have a form in textview where the user entered details to be replaced the specific word in the specific place.
I cannot able to find the right guidance from the various searches, where I can only find to format the text/color, etc. My object is to replace the existing text with user filled data.

```
     import UIKit

class SandyaViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
   func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "SViewController" {
            if let nextVC = segue.destination  as? SPViewController {
            nextVC.yourName = self.nameTextField.text!
            nextVC.address = self.addressTextField.text!
            }
        }
    }
}    
    class SPViewController: UIViewController {
    var yourName: String!
    var address: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var formTextView: UITextView!

    myTextView.text = "This is to certify , that I yourname  residing at home address....."

   let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "This is to certify , that I your name  residing at home address .........\n")

let attributes1: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
   NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 153/255, green: 51/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0),
   NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15)!,
   NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
]
attributedString.addAttributes(attributes1, range: NSMakeRange(28, 9))

let attributes3: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [
   NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0),
   NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor: UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 1.0)
]
attributedString.addAttributes(attributes3, range: NSMakeRange(51, 12))
```

Here I want the replace the attributes1 value with yourName and attributes3 value with address 
myTextView.text = "This is to certify , that I attributes1  residing at home attributes3....."
I assume the I have detailed properly
Thanks

Comment: Please share your code, because it’s not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You don't say where are used `yourName` and `address` in your attributedString.

Comment: I want to replace the user entered value from the textfield in the form of TextView which is placed in the next view controller

Comment: Use something like that instead `"This is to certify , that I <NAME_PLACEHOLDER>  residing at home <ADDRESS_PLACEHOLDER>..."`. Then create an `NSAttributedString` with effects for name. Then find the range of `<NAME_PLACEHOLDER> `, then use `replaceCharacters(in range:rangeFoundForNAME_PLACEHOLDER, with attrString:nameAttributedString)`.

Comment: Thanks but possible to show with an example?

Comment: What part exactly? Decompose and check what you can do, what you don't know how to do, then do a search about that... : Retrieve range of Substring, Create NSAttributedString (you seem to know that already), Just call `replaceCharacters(in range:rangeFoundForNAME_PLACEHOLDER, with attrString:nameAttributedString)`. Where are you blocked?

Comment: Being new, Tried tried and tired. Need guidance with example code and the location to place for `replaceCharacters(in range:rangeFoundForNAME_PLACEHOLDER, with attrString:nameAttributedString)`   Also, I am looking for yourName to be replaced  in more than one occurrence and to be replaced all at a time. Thanks

Comment: followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417224/how-to-replace-exact-keyword-in-a-sentence-in-uitextview) and works fine. Thanks